# Problems when trying to use data from an API in a React component

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am creating my first React application in a project and it is a CEP searcher (a number created by the Brazilian post office to facilitate the sending of parcels). I am using an API to get this data, I used Axios to request them from the API, I get the data, but when I pass it to a component, the component is not created and I am sure that the data is taken by the API and that the component was made correctly. I made my code like this:

```
const getCepData =  async () => {

        const { data } = await axios.get(`https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/05424020`)
        console.log(data)
        return (
            <>
                <CepInfoContainer info={ data }/>
            </>
        ); 
    }
```

Comment: You can't have an `async` component. Typically this would be split into two parts - a service and a component - and you'll need to read up on _hooks_.

Comment: I would load the data in a `useEffect` hook and set a new state accordingly. After that I would conditionally render a circular progress or the component respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your logic with useState and useEffect like this

```
const getCepData = () => {
      const [data, setData] = useState([])
      
      useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get(`https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/05424020`);
            setData(result);
            }
        fetchData();
      },[]) 
      
        return (
            <>
                <CepInfoContainer info={ data }/>
            </>
        ); 
    }
```

Comment: hello @Evren, thanks for the answer, but one thing I forgot to mention is that this function will be activated by the button, because I want the user to type a CEP code and then click on the button and the data, such as state and city, appear. I know this way with useEffect, is it possible to use this method and do it onclick?

Comment: Yes you can use same function inside onClick, you do not need useEffect. Just set your initial data with a value that does not break your CepInfoContainer component @EduardWild